# Mongoose - Nodejs delete string inside array using pull

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pull

So like the title said I wanna delete string inside array using pull.

Here is what I tried to do without success:

```
app.post("/accomodation-imgdelete", (req, res, next) => {
  Accomodation.findOneAndUpdate(
    { email: req.session.passport.user },
    { $pull: {images: 2},
    function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
    })
});
```

React post:

```
  deleteImage = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios({
      url: "/authentication/accomodation-imgdelete",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        image:event.target.name,
      },
    })
      .then(console.log('works'))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

And here is a screenshot of my db:https://gyazo.com/9c44c169bfffb0aa48bdc876b1361d4c

So I wanna delete the number 2 from the image array.

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: So you want to remove an element of a subdocument array using the array index position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My node code is right I had some issues in React I was getting the wrong element.

-Thanks